# Cache behavior using Firestore in Flutter and Native Code

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering if FlutterFire's Firestore uses the same cache as the Android and iOS native Firestore libraries.

**Current setup:**
We have the app written for Android and iOS separately using the native Android/iOS client library for the platform.

**Future setup:**
We still have most parts of the app written in Android and iOS using the native libraries, but some parts may be written in Flutter to start sharing more and more code.
We would like to use FlutterFire in the Flutter parts.

Now I'm wondering if the Firestore Flutter SDK will share the cache with the native SDKs, so we don't accidentally cache the same things twice on one device, just because of the dual setup of Flutter with existing native code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flutter SDK for Firestore is just a wrapper around the native SDKs for Android and iOS, so I'm fairly certain that direct access from the native SDK is effectively the same as access via Flutter, and they will use the same local cache.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks, I see that sounds reasonable.
I wasn't aware that the Flutter SDK for Firestore just passes the work to the native SDKs.